# dotfuscator and localization in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, dotfuscator

i have a problem with the dotfuscor.
I'm using a app with localization and i bind the data like:

```
Text="{Binding Path=Localizedresources.Foo, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

or

```
Header="{Binding Localizedresources.Today, Mode=OneWay}" DataContext="{StaticResource LocalizedStrings}"
```

the problem is, that dotfuscator dont likes this and i get the message e.g.:

```
XamlAnalysis flagged something in Resource Main.g.resources\mainpage.xaml at (111, 55) for the following reasons: Binding expression {Binding Localizedresources.Today, Mode=OneWay} :Could not resolve, may have to manually exclude.
```

but i dont know how to fix it or even how to exclude this because i dont know in which step the error is like "string encryption".

how to solve this?

Comment: I would just try excluding it from the string encryption step and then try other steps too if it didn't solve it. I've had to do similar things on previous dotfuscator releases when my only feedback was that the app crashed in the emulator, so at least your situation should be quicker :)